Slow Performance on MySQL Update Query for Large Table
I am working on a MySQL procedure that performs an update on a Products table with over 25,000 records. The procedure is running(often locking) very slowly, and I need help optimizing it for better performance.
Problem:
The procedure updates the IsActive and IsDeleted fields in the Products table based on a comparison with the TemporaryProducts table. Specifically, it does the following:
Finds products in the Products table whose Name field does not exist in the TemporaryProducts table's StoreType field.
Sets IsActive = 0 and IsDeleted = 1 for those products in Products table.
Here is the current procedure:
BEGIN
    UPDATE Products 
    SET IsActive = 0, IsDeleted = 1
    WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT StoreType FROM TemporaryProducts)
    AND IsActive = 1 AND IsDeleted = 0;
END;

Table Structures
Products Table:

Over 25,000 records
Relevant columns:


Name: VARCHAR(255)
IsActive: TINYINT
IsDeleted: TINYINT

TemporaryProducts Table:

Over 25,000 records
Relevant column:


StoreType: VARCHAR(255)

What I Tried:
Indexes:
Added indexes to the relevant fields in both tables:
Products: (Name, IsActive, IsDeleted)
TemporaryProducts: (StoreType)
Replaced NOT IN with LEFT JOIN: I tried using a LEFT JOIN to rewrite the query as follows:
UPDATE Products p
LEFT JOIN TemporaryProducts t ON p.Name = t.StoreType
SET p.IsActive = 0, p.IsDeleted = 1
WHERE t.StoreType IS NULL
AND p.IsActive = 1 AND p.IsDeleted = 0;

My Questions:

What other strategies can I use to optimize this update query for better performance?

What are the potential bottlenecks causing the query to run slowly, even after adding indexes?


Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

use an not EXISTS instead of NOT IN, but what does the EXPLAIN UPDATE say to your query

Update and delete over large dataset should be done in chunks.

Two things you can try to make this work better.

Put an index on Products (IsActive, IsDeleted, Name). Those are the same columns as a compound index you already have, but with Name last. That may support your WHERE clause a bit better than the index you have.

Put LIMIT 100 or something like that on your UPDATE query. Then repeat it in a loop until ROW_COUNT() comes up zero. This will reduce the size of the individual queries and make each one take less.
Obvisously if you need all the changes to be made in an "atomic" fashion so other users of your tables don't notice a partially completed update, you can't do this.


